# Jenkins "forgets" parameters when executing a shell script in Build section

Tags: shell, jenkins, parameters

I encounter the issue that I have a parameterized project with several string parameters, e.g., "VARIABLE_A", and that Jenkins doesn't know them anymore when executing a shell script in the Build section, i.e., there is simply no value.

This is very bizarre and I am convinced this should work using a string parameter (variable) in these ways:
"echo $VARIABLE_A"
"python3 $PATH/abc.py $VARIABLE_A"
...
but there is no values anymore.
echo-command does not print anything and the Python script misses the value as VARIABLE_A is apparently empty.

Perhaps someone has an idea ?

Thanks
Rainer

PS
Jenkins version is "2.277.2".

Comment: Are you expecting `python3 $PATH/abc.py VARIABLE_A` to replace the string `VARIABLE_A` with the contents of the shell variable `VARIABLE_A`? This is not how it's supposed to happen. You need to expand the value using `$VARIABLE_A` the way you did for `echo`

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, youa re right, I forgot to put the "$" here in this post. I have corrected it.

Comment: How is the parameter value set?

Comment: The parameter value is set as default value of the "String Parameter" named "VARIABLE_A".  

This project is parameterized  
 String Parameter  
  Name  
   VARIABLE_A  
  Default value  
   ABC  
  Description  
   some description text